# Why the php files weren't executed by cron job?

Tags: php, wordpress, cron, cpanel

I have 2 cron jobs to run 2 php files, The first one should be executed each 12 hours (twice a day 12am and 12pm), The second one should be executed each 12h:45m (12 hours and 45 minutes).

The Cpanel timezone is EDT (Eastern Daylight Time), I set the cron jobs at 2pm EDT timezone yesterday, Now it's 8:25 am and the files weren't executed.

Here is a screenshot of the cron jobs:
[image: Cron Jobs Screenshot]

And here is an example from Cpanel:
[image: Cron Job Example From Cpanel]

When I searched how to do it the command contains `-q` before the php file path, So I added it, It's not in the command example.

It that the problem or what?

Comment: Are you sure that the php binary is located in the /usr/local/bin directory ? Maybe you can try to remove the path information and just run `php -q /home/user/path/to/script.php`

Comment: @DavidLeBorgne, No i'm not sure, How to be sure?

Comment: Run the command "where php" or look in the already existing processes the full path to it.